# Debugging kernel with /proc/kcore

Tags: linux, debugging, linux-kernel, gdb

I was learning debugging kernel using /proc/kcore

I built the latest stable 4.19 Linux version and installed it on my virtual machine.

Then I cd into the folder where my linux source code was compiled and run the following command.

```
sudo gdb vmlinux /proc/kcore
```

It gave me the following errors

```
Core was generated by `BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.19.6 root=UUID=c17d5f82-e020-4ded-a082-89fd7e54d893'.
#0  0x0000000000000000 in irq_stack_union ()
warning: File "/home/jamal/linux/linux-4.19.6/scripts/gdb/vmlinux-gdb.py" auto-loading has been declined by your `auto-load safe-path' set to "$debugdir:$datadir/auto-load".
To enable execution of this file add
    add-auto-load-safe-path /home/jamal/linux/linux-4.19.6/scripts/gdb/vmlinux-gdb.py
line to your configuration file "/home/jamal/.gdbinit".
To completely disable this security protection add
    set auto-load safe-path /
line to your configuration file "/home/jamal/.gdbinit".
For more information about this security protection see the
"Auto-loading safe path" section in the GDB manual.  E.g., run from the shell:
    info "(gdb)Auto-loading safe path"
```

So, I added

```
$ cat /home/jamal/.gdbinit 
add-auto-load-safe-path /home/jamal/linux/linux-4.19.6/scripts/gdb/vmlinux-gdb.py
```

Then when I tried to refresh kcore file and print 'jiffies' value it is printing the same value again and again. What is the mistake I am making here.

```
Reading symbols from vmlinux...done.
[New process 1]
Core was generated by `BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.19.6 root=UUID=c17d5f82-e020-4ded-a082-89fd7e54d893'.
#0  0x0000000000000000 in irq_stack_union ()
(gdb) print jiffies
$1 = 4294892296
(gdb) core-file /proc/kcore
[New process 1]
Core was generated by `BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.19.6 root=UUID=c17d5f82-e020-4ded-a082-89fd7e54d893'.
#0  0x0000000000000000 in irq_stack_union ()
(gdb) print jiffies
$2 = 4294892296
(gdb) 
$3 = 4294892296
(gdb) q
```

Answer (score 1):

You should set the following in your `.gdbinit`:

```
set auto-load safe-path /
```

Then source or reboot your machine to make it take effect.